# Request a "get operation" from Google Speech to text API using Python Speech Client

Tags: python, google-api-python-client, google-speech-api

I'm looking for a way to [get operations](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/operations/get) related to the Google speech API using the [official Google Python Client](https://github.com/googleapis/python-speech).

There seems to be some ability to interact with the `List Operations` and `Get Operations` apis, as shown [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/speech/latest/gapic/v1p1beta1/types.html#google.cloud.speech_v1p1beta1.types.GetOperationRequest). However, the [only three methods](https://github.com/googleapis/python-speech/blob/master/google/cloud/speech_v1p1beta1/gapic/speech_client.py) that seem to be exposed by the client are recognize, long_running_recognize, and streaming_recognize. (I linked the Beta docs, but the non-beta seem to be the same).

Is there a way to do this through the Python client, without just hitting the HTTP route directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching more, one user in [this github issue](https://github.com/googleapis/python-speech/issues/8#issue-559388522) posted a couple solutions:

1)

```
    client = speech.SpeechClient()
    api = operations_v1.OperationsClient(client.transport.channel)
    op = api.get_operation(operation_name)
```

For him, this did not return metadata, though for me (using  `google.cloud.speech_v1p1beta`) it did return some metadata, but not all (e.g., did return name, did not return others such as startTime, progressPercent, etc).

2)

```
speech_service = discovery.build('speech', 'v1p1beta1')
operation = speech_service.operations().get(name=operation_name).execute()
```

(not calling `execute` will return a Google http request object rather than an operation). This worked better, and returned an object more like the operation object returned by the original `long_running_recognize` request.

I have still not found official documentation for either solution though. There is the example that can more or less be inductively derived from the [source code](https://github.com/googleapis/python-speech/blob/3aca5051eb10463ce05a0d333c2eedc6c49406bd/google/cloud/speech_v1/gapic/transports/speech_grpc_transport.py#L80).

Comment: This doesn't work with Google Speech v `2.xx` where the `client.transport` no longer provides the `channel` field. related: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/9101